# How to configure @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties in webpack.config.js?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am seeing `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` as recommended alternative to using `babel-preset-stage-0`.

In my current react app, I use `webpack.config.js` instead of `babel.rc` or any thing else. I am left wondering how do I configure this `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` plugin in `webpack.config.js` file. The [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) isn't talking about it and so I'm seeking the help from you.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `use: {
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    plugins: [
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }]
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass options to the [babel-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/) by using the [options](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options) property.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.m?js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer, Veli Šiška, helped me with a babel issue for which other replies always answered to configure `.babelrc` or the `main.js` of Nuxt.

In my case I use `React` with `webpack.config.ts`

So I copy it here in case it can help somebody else in my situation.

```
Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties.
The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }]
to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.
Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object.
The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was to add one line in `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`. At first that file looked *totally* intimidating, but it does make sense. If you look for something like this...

```js
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
        { ... },

        // First, run the linter.
        // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
        { ... },

        {
          // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
          // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
          // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
          oneOf: [

           // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
            // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
            // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
            { ... },

            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            { ... },

            // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
            // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true },
                  ],
                ],

                // !!!! THIS IS THE LINE TO ADD. NOTHING ELSE. !!!!
                plugins: [ '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties' ],
                ...
```

**Notes**

- My problem seemed to be with javascript files that weren't in my react app's `src` folder ("outside of the app"), which is why i changed that particular rule. 
  My main app javascript files don't generate the error so they must be
  transpiling/bundling correctly using the previous rule which deals
  with application JS. It may be you need add the
  `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` plugin to the previous rule
  instead.
- I needed to run `yarn add --dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`
- I don't have a `.babelrc` or  `babel.config.js` file, nor a `babel` property in `package.json`.

Also, this is tweaking a node module. The change will be destroyed the next time you do anything significant with npm/yarn. I used the well known [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) module to quickly spit out a self-applying patch.

*Project details: react 16, babel 7, webpack 4*